# How can I best capture what software a contact is using on our platform?

Tags: contact, setup

I'm setting up our new instance of Salesforce. We have a need to setup our contact fields to track what software that contact is using. We own several platforms and have a need to message the users differently based on activity.

I see our implementation in three phases:

1. Capture software usage. That is if we have A, B, and C we need to
   know if user 1 is using A and B or just C (or any combination of
   those). This is just the setup.
2. We intend to integrate with these platforms via API to import users automatically. If a user logs in to one of the 3 items for the first time a new record will be created. If they use more than one we want to update the existing record with the additional login.
3. We want to track login frequency and usage to report so that we can message users appropriately. May be automated, may not be.

I get that this is relatively complicated. The most important thing is to setup the contact records in such a way that 2 and 3 are reasonable. Think of 2 and 3 above as context.

Thanks and I couldn't find a duplicate so please mod if I missed something.

Comment: Hi Graham, welcome to SF.SE. When you say "track what software that contact is using" are you speaking of what application they're accessing in your Salesforce instance? You mention users logging in via an API, which API are you speaking of? Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The more details you provide, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer that you'll find helpful. You can update your question by clicking on edit at the bottom left.

Comment: Sorry, it is a complicated question. Our company have several internal applications (Internal Stack, Internal Github, and a couple others). We want to pull new users in to the CRM and know the source. There will be one initial source (Internal Stack, Internal Github, etc.) but we also want to know what other software the user is using. So, if the record is created from a Github login but the user later logs in to Stack we want to know that they are users of both. I'm working to make sure we get this setup correctly the first time to avoid issues down the road.

Comment: Will each of these log-ins have the same SSO configuration with your SF instance or will they be unique? I don't think you could use a referrer like you would with a web link unless you're logging them in through a VisualFlow from each of your applications. SF also has the ability to look at cookies.

Comment: Yes they will have the same SSO configuration. I'm not so much concerned with how, we have a dev team for that. I'm more interested in where the best place to capture the app data. Very newb here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain there is "one best place". The best place will be what's most convenient for you. You'll want it to be where you can write data to the platform. If cookies exist that you're able to read or "recognize" for the other apps, that would be one approach. Talk to your dev team handling the SSO to see what data they'll have access to as that would be the other avenue. They'd have to capture the data at log-in via the log-in and registration controllers.